# Adjusting a timestamp with a timezone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone-offset

I'm using postgres and I have a timestamp without a timezone and a timezone offset in the form of '-2'. How would I apply the offset to the timezone? I know that something like date - interval '2 hours' would work for a fixed offset, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do it with a variable from another column.

Comment: Can you post some sample data?  Both inputs and expected outputs. What is the format of the "variable from another column"?

Comment: `2015-10-17 05:33:09` and `-5` and I want it to be `2015-10-17 00:33:09`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick for you:

```
CASE WHEN offset_var > 0 THEN timestamp_no_tz + (offset_var || ' hour')::INTERVAL 
WHEN offset_var < 0 THEN timestamp_no_tz - (abs(offset_var) || ' hour')::INTERVAL 
ELSE timestamp_no_tz END
```